# Trouble subsetting in R with %in%

Tags: r

For some reason I am running into a problem using the `%in%` operator to remove subjects in a single data frame that do not have values for two separate time points.  My data frame is in long format and of this type:

```
Subject Group Timepoint word.RT
399     1        t1     979
399     1        t1     818
399     1        t1     761
399     1        t1    1066
399     1        t2     855
399     1        t2    1338
399     1        t2     834
399     1        t2    1018
```

The data is in a simple .csv file.

Because this study is still ongoing and there is missing data some subjects have only `t1` data and others only have `t2` data. In order to subset subjects that only have both `t1` and `t2` data I have been using (and used successfully in the past) the following code:

```
dat <- dat[dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"] %in% 
           dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t2"],]

dat <- dat[dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t2"] %in% 
           dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"],]
```

The odd thing is this works for some subjects but not for others and I've even had the instance in which it will work for one subject, then I'll shut down R, reload everything, try again and it won't work for some of the subjects it has worked for previously.  I've made sure that every subject's timepoint is coded as either `t1` or `t2` and there are no weird formatting things going on like a random space somewhere.  Are there errors like this that people have when subsetting with the `%in%` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encourage you to learn and use either `dplyr` or `data.table` for this kind of thing.  Either will work well, but probably best to pick one to start with and become familiar with it. Both have their adherents. Either will make your life immeasurably easier.  I show both options here.  In this instance, maybe the dplyr one looks slightly simpler, but for other operations data.table will be the more succinct:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  filter(all(c('t1','t2') %in% Timepoint))

library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, both := all(c('t1','t2') %in% Timepoint), by = Subject][both == TRUE]
```

Comment: Another method with `data.table` might be `dat[, n_timepoints := uniqueN(Timepoint)]` then `dat[n_timepoints == 2]`

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I am familiar with dplyr but was looking for a way to do this without a package because I use plyr quite a bit and I'm always running into problems when I use the ddply function and dplyr has been loaded.  My apologies, I should have made that more clear in my original post.  The data.table way seems like the best way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
dat <- dat[dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"] %in% 
           dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t2"],]
```

with:

```
subj_of_interest <- unique(with(dat, Subject[which(timepoint=='t2')]))
dat[with(dat,which(Timepoint=='t1' & (Subject %in% subj_of_interest))),]
```

Part of your problem in the code is that when you subset on the LHS of `%in%` it will return a vector of T/F that is shorter than the row number of `dat`.  This means that the T/F vector used to retrieve results doesn't map 1-1 to what you expect it to and could seem a little odd or be completely and obviously wrong depending on your dataset.

I also recomment using `which()` as it will automatically exclued `NAs`, whereas not using which will return `TRUE`s and `NA` results

Comment: I'm curious about your second line of code, it seems that you would need to change 't1' to 't2' and that way you are getting a new data.frame in which subjects that have 't2' values also exist in the 'subj_of_interest' vector which are subjects with 't1' values. In other words any subjects that has 't2' values also have 't1' values, which is what I'm looking for.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @wilcoxr, you are correct, of course.  The change is made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that 
`dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"] %in% dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t2"]`
is a boolean vector of length 
`length(dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"])`, 
not of length `length(dat$Subject)` as you would require. This could lead to some unexpected behaviour. I would suggest the following:

```
subjects_with_both_ts <- dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"]
[dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t1"] %in% dat$Subject[dat$Timepoint=="t2"]
dat <- dat[dat$Subject %in% subjects_with_both_ts,]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more natural way to solve this to me is to reshape the data to a wide format.  However, your data is ill-suited for this.  You don't have a unique identifier (i.e. no combination of columns uniquely identify the variable of interest, word.RT).  This is not best practices.  Below is an approach that both generates a unique identifier and solves your problem.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  group_by(Timepoint)%>%
  mutate(Timepoint_Key = sequence(n())) %>%
  spread(Timepoint, word.RT) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.))
```

If you want to go back to long append

```
  gather(TimePoint,t1, -Subject,-Group, -key) %>%
  rename(word.RT = t1)
```